# Which map data should I use to write a routing program on a map?

Tags: c++, gis, openstreetmap, shapefile

I have the shapefiles of my town and i want to write a routing program in c++ on it. To be able to write routing application, to which format should I convert these shapefiles?

Comment: That depends entirely on *your* routing program. I would prefer reading raw [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) (or PBF) for generating the initial routing graph. Then just use your routing graph.

Comment: Yes @scai , I was suspect that is shapefile enough for routing or  should I use another data file (or in combination with shapefile)? So your answer to this question is that shapefile is not enough?

Comment: Honestly I don't know what this shapefile contains. OSM data is usually exchanged using OSM XML or PBF format. There are very few cases in which a shapefile should be used. Routing is definitely none of them.